# How to locate a ng-reflect ng class attribute in protractor?Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, automated-tests

```
<div _ngcontent-c3="" class="bs-massage typ-user active" ng-reflect-klass="bs-massage  typ-user active" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" id="msg_user_step_2">
    <p _ngcontent-c3="" class="msg">
        cvds sadf
    </p>
    <a _ngcontent-c3="" class="btn btn-icon btn-edit">
    </a>
    <div _ngcontent-c3="" class="timestamp">
        <time _ngcontent-c3="" class="time" datetime="11:00">
            5:28 PM
        </time>
    </div>
</div>
```

Error:

> Failed No element found using locator

Please help me to locate this element using the following code:

```
describe("Application Form", function()
        {
            it(" DETAILS", function()
            {
                browser.get("http://localhost:4200/online-application-form.html/Personal");
               element(by.css("bs-massage type-user active").sendKeys("username1"));
var el = element(by.id('msg_user_step_3'));
            el.sendKeys("username 2");

     });
    });
```

or:

```
var el = element(by.id('msg_user_step_3'));
el.sendKeys("username 2");
```

Answer (score 1):

There are actually few problems on this line:

```
element(by.css("bs-massage type-user active").sendKeys("username1"));
```

First of all, there is a misplacement of a closing parenthesis.

And the second class name is `typ-user`, not `type-user` (at least judging by the HTML code you've provided in the question).

And, *multiple classes need to be "chained" with dots*:

```
element(by.css(".bs-massage.typ-user.active")).sendKeys("username1");
```

Comment: it displays  Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, .bs-massage.typ-user.active)

Comment: <div _ngcontent-c3="" class="bs-massage typ-user active" ng-reflect-klass="bs-massage  typ-user active" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" id="msg_user_step_5">
     <p _ngcontent-c3="" class="msg">Single</p>
     <a _ngcontent-c3="" class="btn btn-icon btn-edit"></a>
           <div _ngcontent-c3="" class="timestamp">
   <time _ngcontent-c3="" class="time" datetime="11:00">1:02 PM</time>
                        </div>
                    </div>           How to above locate element in Protractor?